# How to prevent AlertDialog from not closing by clicking outside?

Tags: flutter

I built an AlertDialog to display Loading while i'm authenticating the user and when it finishes i pop it.

```
Widget loadingDialog = new AlertDialog(
content: new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    new CircularProgressIndicator(),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
      child: new Text("Loading..."),
    ),
  ],
),);
```

But, if the user taps outside the Dialog it closes. So when the auth finishes, it will still pop something (i guess the scaffol), breaking the app.
How can i make Dialog not closable?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There is a property inside `showDialog` called `barrierDismissible`. Setting this value to false will make your AlertDialog not closable by clicking outside.

```
showDialog(
   ...
   barrierDismissible: false,
   ...
```

Comment: Nice. The tricky part is that for some reason I thought this property would be a part of `AlertDialog` (probably, Android habits). Makes more sence the way it is, though.

Answer (score 11):

To prevent dismissing of dialog on press of a back button, you should also wrap your `AlertDialog` (or any other widget) inside a `WillPopScope`.

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false, // <-- Set this to false.
  builder: (_) => WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false, // <-- Prevents dialog dismiss on press of back button.
    child: AlertDialog(...),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

// User Defined Function
void _showloding() {

```
// flutter defined function
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false, // JUST MENTION THIS LINE
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    // return object of type Dialog
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Container(height: 100,width: 100,child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: SizedBox(height: 50,width: 50,child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Center(child: Text("Processing")),
            )
          ],
        )),
      )
    );
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent dialog close when back button pressed then refer below code. You need to wrap the AlertDialog in WillPopScope widget and make onWillPop property value with function which return Future.value(false).

```
showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,    //this will prevent popup closing when touch outside of popup
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(        // Wrap in WillPopScope widget
            onWillPop: () => Future.value(false), //this line will prevent popup closing when back button of phone press 
            child:AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Alert Title"),
            content: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(),),
            actions: [
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        )
      },
    );
```