# Prevent dialog from closing on outside touch in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dialog, dart, flutter

In Flutter, I write a simple dialog for the loader during async task. When I touch outside dialog dismissed, How can I stop this behaviour?

**Code**

```
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => new Dialog(
          child: new Container(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            height: 80.0,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                new Padding(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: new Text("Loading"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635395/how-to-set-alertdialog-to-dont-close-clicking-outside-in-flutter/50635504#50635504   Answer already available there

Answer (score 307, accepted):

There's a property called `barrierDismissible` that you can pass to `showDialog` ; which makes dialogs dismissible or not on external click

```
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: ...
)
```

Comment: how to handle `barrierDismissible`.. like when click outside adding different activity

Comment: In Android you are still able to close the dialog by pressing the BACK button. Is there a way to prevent this as well?

Comment: Alex you can enclose the dialog builder widget with a WillPopScope. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/how-to-deactivate-or-override-the-android-back-button-in-flutter

Comment: If you are using `showModalBottomSheet` then you need to turn the `isDismissible: false`

Comment: `showCupertinoDialog` also has this property.

Comment: barrierDismissible is does not prevent dailog from closing if i am use back gesture

Answer (score 56):

If you want to prevent dialog close when back button pressed then refer below code. You have to wrap your AlertDialog in WillPopScope widget and make onWillPop property value with function which return Future.value(false).

```
showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
            child:AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Alert Title"),
            content: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(),),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        )
      },
    );
```

Comment: It is impossible to use `onWillPop: (){}` now.
The appropriate variant is `onWillPop: () => Future.value(false)`

Comment: Or `onWillPop: () async => false,`

Comment: @ValentinaKonyukhova Yes you are right. I have updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: thanks this solution to prevent all dismiss method

Answer (score 19):

**just Add this Line**

```
barrierDismissible: false,
```

**like as**

```
       showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(
              "Classes",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24, color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'intel'),
            ),
            content: setupAlertDialoadClassList(
                context, listClasses, Icons.class__outlined, 0),
          );
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

**barrierDismissible: false,**

Use this one as I described below.
showDialog(
barrierDismissible: false,
builder  // code //

Answer (score 5):

This will disable device navigation

```
showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async => false,
            child:AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Alert Title"),
            content: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(),),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        )
      },
    );
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed because while `barrierDismissible: false,` prevented closing by clicking outside the dialog, you could still close it by hitting the back button.

Answer (score 2):

Always use top flutter packages like [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

```
Get.generalDialog(pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        ...
      );
    }, barrierDismissible: false /* its default value */);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need with getX package

Comment: Bad advice. You absolutely do not need to use GetX.

Also, just avoid using GetX, in general.

Answer (score 1):

1. Phone navigation bar action disabled

> canPop: false

2. disable outer touch in AlertDialog

> barrierDismissible: false

**use this code**

```
void alert() {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false, // <-- Set this to false.
          builder: (_) => PopScope(
            canPop: false, // <-- Prevents dialog dismiss on press of back button.
            child: AlertDialog(),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this property in your showDialog **barrierDismissible: false** to prevent it from closing from outside touch.

```
showDialog(
   barrierDismissible: false,
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ar not using a showDialog, otherwise you'r using GestureDetectore, there's a easy way i just did, Just put a GestureDetector inside another one, then set the onTap action if that's your case on both GestureDetector's, with the diference that in one you are gonna put an action, an in the other one you can just leave it empty, just like this.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () { //The Gesture you dont want to afect the rest
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child:GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {}, //This way is not going to afect the inside widget
            child: Container() //your widget
            )
          )
        )
```