# Prevent to hide showModalBottomSheet from outside touch

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to prevent `ModalBottomSheet` to hide from outside touch? Like in `showDialog()` we can use **`barrierDismissible`** [property to prevent dialog from closing on outside touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649006/prevent-dialog-from-closing-on-outside-touch-in-flutter)

Answer (score 6):

you can use `isDismissible: false` and `enableDrag: false` like this

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      isDismissible: false,
      enableDrag: false,

      builder: (context) {
        return Container(
         height: 100.0
       )
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `showBottomSheet()` which doesn't include barrier instead of using `showModalBottomSheet()`.

More info [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html)

Comment: Sorry guys, I know for ``showBottomSheet  but I'm looking for showModalBottomSheet().

Comment: The only difference between `showModalBottomSheet` and `showBottomSheet` is the latter can't be dismissed by touching outside of its context. And isn't the same thing you asked for?

Comment: Yes but I think we can access/touch outer widget after opening the `showBottomSheet ` ? Correct me if I'm wrong ?

Comment: You are right, you can access outer widgets, may I know what exact model you are looking for? You simply want to prevent those outer widgets from getting clicked when sheet is opened? You can use `AbsorbPointer` widget for that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    VoidCallback _showPersBottomSheetCallback;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _showPersBottomSheetCallback = _showBottomSheet;
    }

    void _showBottomSheet() {
        setState(() {
        _showPersBottomSheetCallback = null;
        });

        _scaffoldKey.currentState
            .showBottomSheet((context) {
            return new Container(
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                height: 300.0,
                child: new Center(
                child: new Text("Hi BottomSheet"),
                ),
            );
            })
            .closed
            .whenComplete(() {
            if (mounted) {
                setState(() {
                _showPersBottomSheetCallback = _showBottomSheet;
                });
            }
            });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Flutter BottomSheet"),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onTap: () {},
            child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            child: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: _showPersBottomSheetCallback,
                    child: new Text("Persistent"),
                    ),
                ],
                ),
            ),
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I consider it to be a workaround instead of a solution when you already have dedicated `showBottomSheet()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting isDismissible to false inside showModalBottomSheet

```
        showModalBottomSheet(
                    isDismissible: false,
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext bc) {
                      return SheetWidget();
                    },
                  );
```

where SheetWidget is the widget you are trying to call as BottomSheet